# Visual Studio Code 1.67.1 - Fails to provide any choices when using snippets

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

results:
[failed choices in VSC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdUEq.png)

## snapshot.code-snippets (code)

```
"Wait4widget": {
    "scope": "javascript",
    "prefix": "wait4widget",
    "body": [
        "await AWS2Page.hoverclickandload${1|lov,popup,subpanel,cmdstack,page,graphicpage|}(page, ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT:JSHandle});"
    ],
    "description": "Add a hover, click, and wait for loading widgets (Ctrl+F2)"
},
```

==================

Issue: in a prior release the snippet with the "non-space" between the text 'load' and $ supported the 6 choices, now I get a dropdown that indicates "no suggestions." and it enters the 1st choice of "lov". If I add a space between the 'load' and the $, it provides the choices (but the space is not desired)

ideas?

### thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me now in Insiders today.  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/149430 fixed it.

So I would expect the fix in Stable v1.68 early June 2022.  I don't see it as an addition to the v1.67.2 Recovery Release yet.

---

It looks like this regression has been recently reported in these two github issues:

[Snippet expansion regression in 1.67](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/148976)
[Snippet choices lost](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/149363)

and the location of the bug is known.  It'll probably be fixed pretty quickly but "may" not make it for the next recovery release (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/milestone/189?closed=1) so you may have to wait until v1.68 unless you use the Insiders Build.

But you should add your finding that a space right before the `${<choice>...` fixes it to the second issue, it might be helpful info.